# Python one-liner for loop with if statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I have a function used for my Pandas dataframe to return the length of each column:

```
def get_col_widths(dataframe)
    return [max([len(str(s)) for s in dataframe[col].values] + [len(col)]) for col in dataframe.columns]
```

However I have a column of dates (of type `numpy.datetime64`) so when you do `len(str(s))` it returns 29 instead of the expected 10 (`MM/DD/YYYY`).

How can I incorporate an if to test if `isinstance(s, np.datetime64)`, return 10 instead of `len(str(s))`?

Comment: Could you cast the data type to string (e.g. `df.assign(date_col=df['date_col'].strftime('%M/%D/%Y'))` before calling the function? The behavior you're reporting seems valid to me... datetime objects don't have a meaningful `len`

Comment: It's a list comprehension, not a "one-liner for loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
def get_col_widths(dataframe):
    return [max([len(str(s)) if not isinstance(s, np.datetime64) else 10 for s in dataframe[col].values] + [len(col)]) for col in dataframe.columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just slip the condition before `for s` like so:

```py
def get_col_widths(dataframe):
     return [max([(len(str(s)) if not isinstance(s, np.datetime64) else 10) for s in dataframe[col].values] + [len(col)]) for col in dataframe.columns]
```

But I would advise against using a one-liner. There is no need to compact everything. Readable code is better.

Answer (score 1):

We do not need for loop here

```
c=col

df[c].astype(str).str.len().max()
```

Comment: @Bijan note that df[c].astype(str) will _not_ result in length 10 strings. 10 is the length of the string format you imposed, but it would ignore hours/minutes/seconds etc. Hence the reason I recommend just casting to your desired format first. If you do this, then this answer will work perfectly.

Comment: For my use-case this will not work. This function is used to set the column width in Excel to fit all the data. However your solution does not take the column _header_ length into account. But this is a really clean solution.